# How do I auto redirect to the login page when the session is expired in Backbone.js?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

How to handle session timeout in backbone marionette view? Because of session timeout my ajax call is failing ( fetch method returning error messages) and I need to redirect user back to login page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is to override `Backbone.sync` and check the return value in the fail case. If it's because the session timed out, redirect to the login page, otherwise process the error.

You can see an example here: https://github.com/davidsulc/marionette-serious-progression-app/blob/master/assets/js/entities/common.js#L107 where unauthorized access is processed differently from "normal" errors. This code is from my [advanced book on Marionette](https://leanpub.com/marionette-serious-progression).

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply. Where to override this method I am overriding all my model from base model. Do I need to override sync in my base model ?

Comment: The best way is to override it in a `BaseModel`. Then make your model inherit from it with `BaseeModel.extend({...`. See for example https://github.com/davidsulc/marionette-serious-progression-app/blob/30f923059d1d713f4974fb21b0a3206ee4fa90b3/assets/js/entities/contact.js#L2

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
myModel.fetch({
    success: function(){
        //do something
    },
    error: function (model, response, options) {
        if(response.status == 401){
            window.location.href = '/login';
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This is a good solution But I am looking for a generic solution where it will handle for all my models, collections and Views. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

The generic solution for you could be to use jQuery’s `ajaxSetup`:

```
var redirectToLogin = function()
{
    App.router.navigate('login', true);
};

$.ajaxSetup(
{
    statusCode: {
        401: redirectToLogin,
        403: redirectToLogin
    }
});
```